# Using NFC in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nfc

I am currently developing an image processing/editing kind of app in which I am applying various effects to an image taken by camera/Gallery.

Recently I read about NFC for windows phone 8, and I would like to use NFC in my app to share the photo to windows phones nearby.

After a bit of googling and researching I came with these two links

http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!proximity-and-nfc/using-nfc-to-exchange-information.html

http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Transfer_an_Image_with_NFC

both are very interesting reads, but being a newbie in this area(NFC). I am seeking for the links/samples that are easy to take a start with.

Please help me with few samples/links if you anytime did some research work for the same.

Helps are always appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Windows Phone 8 uses the Proximity API for NFC communication. You can browse sample code and documentation at the [Windows Dev Center Proximity page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207060(v=vs.105).aspx). For your purposes I'd recommend checking out the [ProximityDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.networking.proximity.proximitydevice.aspx) class, which includes links to samples at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

I can't share more than one link for my low reputation so I have putted them all here:
http://bitly.com/bundles/o_1bg5sp2b27/1

I especially recommend the youtube video.

Answer (score 0):

And for testing things out in the emulator, you can use the Proximity Tapper tool below. You can run two emulators on the same computer (they must be different resolutions though), then use the tool below to simulate as if you tapped the two devices together and it'll even show you the data flowing across.

For your use you'll likely want to use the PeerFinder API which uses NFC only to bootstrap a connection over Bluetooth/Wifi, then gives you a StreamSocket over which you send your data. The NFC link is slow relative to Bluetooth/Wifi so it's not practical to send the image directly over that. The PeerFinder API does all the heavy lifting for you, and it's also supported/interoperable on big Windows as well.

http://proximitytapper.codeplex.com/